# The equivalence of [K(x, fix_elem) for x in my_list] using map()

Tags: python, mapping, list-comprehension

Suppose I have the list `my_list = list(range(10))`. In using `map()`, what is the equivalence of `[K(x, fix_elem) for x in my_list]`? At the beginning, I thought `map(K, my_list)` was fine, but I have a fixed element `fix_elem` which is incompatible with my demand.

Comment: `list(map(lambda x: K(x, fix_elem), my_list))`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use map and lambda: `list(map(lambda x: K(x, fix_elem), list(range(10))))`